# Замена определённых символов в тексте на соответствующие теги

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст:

```
<p>Это очень *жирный* текст</p>
```

Необходимо, чтобы было так:

```
<p>Это очень <strong>жирный</strong> текст</p>
```

Как это сделать, при том, что между знаками `*` может быть любой текст?

Answer (score 1):

В простейшем виде, достаточно такого выражения для замены:

```
/\*([\s\S]*?)\*/g  -->  <strong>$1</strong>
```

```js
let rExp = /\*([\s\S]*?)\*/g;
let sTxt = '<p>Это очень *жирный* текст</p>';
console.log( sTxt.replace(rExp, '<strong>$1</strong>') );
```

Но, задача усложняется, если учитывать, что...

> при этом внутри знаков ** может быть любой текст

ведь символ `*` может быть и вложенным. Для подобных случаев, необходимо предусмотреть экранирующие последовательности.

В виду отсутствия чётких условий, один из вариантов может быть таким:

```js
let rExp = /\*([\s\S]*?[^\\])\*/g;
source.oninput = () => {
  view.innerHTML = target.value = source.value.replace(rExp, (s, g) => {
    return `<strong>${g.replace(/\\\*/g, '*')}</strong>`;
  });
};
/*   Only for example --> */source.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

```html
<!-- Only for example --><textarea id="source">Охватить все варианты регулярными выражениями *довольно проблематично*. Необходимо дополнительно проинформировать пользователя на предмет допустимого синтаксиса для форматирования контента.</textarea><textarea id="target" readonly></textarea><p id="view"></p><style>body{display:flex;justify-content:space-between;gap:10px}#source,#target,#view{margin:0;height:170px;width:100%;resize:none}strong{color:red}</style>
```